# Transfer android to mobile device

Tags: android

I have develop an app using Android Studio and i am using java as my language my program worked just fine when i run it on android studio using an emulator.  I am very new in using android so please excuse my not so intelligent question, can I turn my program and upload it or transfer it to my mobile device with out using or with out uploading it to Google play?  Just like my normal program which i have develop in eclipse using the same language java, which i could export directly to a desktop or laptop by converting it to a runnable jar file.  Any comment or answer would be be very much appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: from what I understand, [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#RealDevice) would be able to help you

Comment: yes you can do this ,I have posted steps for that try it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can test you application in mobile device for that you have to follow below steps:

**1 >** Open Setting

**2 >** open Developer Option if you dont see that option then you have to open it using 7 times Click on Build Number section

**Stock Android:** Settings > About phone > Build number

**Samsung Galaxy S5:** Settings > About device > Build number

**LG G3:** Settings > About phone > Software information > Build number

**HTC One (M8):** Settings > About > Software information > More > Build number

After this you can see Developer option.

**3 >** Open Developer Option

**4 >**  tap on the ON/OFF  on the top of the page.

**5 >** select USB Debugging

**6 >** Now allow All permission And run you program you can see your device in ADB select it and RUN